# expected ';' , ' :' or '(' before constant

Tags: c, function

The error is marked in the #define, but I'm unsure where is the problem or how to fix it.

This is probably filled with mistakes, so any feedback is welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 6

void fil_array(int* A,int const N);
void print_array(int* A,int const N);
    
int main()
{
    int i,A[N];
    srand(time(NULL));
    fil_array(A, N);
    print_array(A, N);
    return 0;
}

void fil_array(int* A, int const N)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        A[i]=rand%21;
}

void print_array(int* A, int const N)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf("A[%d]=%d\n", i,A[i]);
}
```

Comment: After preprocessing: https://godbolt.org/z/q91v6fcv3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is naming conflict in your code. Macro name `#define N 6` and `int const N` this 2 name are conflicted. Use different name to solve this. There is one more things I want to share. In this line `A[i]=rand%21;` rand should be a function name. The correct way is `A[i]=rand()%21;`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `int const N` you should make this parameter `int n` - pick a different name than the macro `N`.

Comment: I tried that but didnt work, still kept giving me same problem, am i dumb

Comment: Nvm I got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is you are naming parameters of your function as a constant defined by prepocessor. I am talking about N.
When compilation chain starts, the preprocessor substitute the value of defined constant in your code, this means that your function prototypes appear like:

```
void fil_array(int* A,int const 6);
```

Because you tell the compiler that N means 6

```
#define N 6
```